# Why substitute input variables with functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, substitution

So you have a function: $f(x,y) = xy$ that graphs some 3 dimensional surface. And for a reason, you need to change the input variables to be functions of $t$. So you let $x = x(t)$ and let $y = y(t)$. After that, you rewrite the function as $f(x(t),y(t)) = xy$. This is quite common to do from my point of view and it doesn't make sense to me.

In general, why do people do this kind of substitution and what is it for? What is the input $t$ mean and how does it relate to the functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$? How does the input $t$ map to the $x$ and $y$ values? I would like to understand this idea so I don't frown the next time I see this done.

Comment: The most basic geometric explanation I can think of is that $(x,y,f(x,y))$ represents a surface; setting $x$ and $y$, $f(x,y)$ can represent a point on the z-axis and you get a surface. However, $f(x(t),y(t))$ means the input is $t$, for every $t$ you get a specific $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, which in turn gives you a value $f(x(t),y(t))$. In this way as you change $t$ you are tracing a CURVE on (x,y,f(x,y)) surface.  So $t$ can be seen as the parameter of the curve.

Comment: @RozaTh Yes, what you said makes sense, but I still don't understand what $t$ is in the context and relation to X and Y. To me, it seems like some arbitrary parameter that magically gets you x and y values. Though, Aidan, the first to answer my question made a point that t can be time as an input for the path of a particle (in Aidan's answer it is the energy of a particle, but since I understood what he said, I made up my own example) where t is a parameterization of the particle's position (x & y coordinates). In addition, your answer isn't complete. You don't mention why people do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think of this is that you are looking at the values of $f(x,y)$ along some path in the $x-y$ plane. For example, maybe $f(x,y)$ represents the energy of a particle in space, and you know that the particle is moving in a circle. You can describe its path by the parametric equations $x(t)=\sin(t),\ y(t)=\cos(t)$, where $t$ represents time. Then $f(x(t),y(t)$ would give the energy of this particle at time t.

The advantage of this approach is that you can provide the value of the energy for arbitrary paths, and you can write it's time derivative in terms of the partial derivatives of $f$, etc. So it simplifies some calculations and allows you to make arguments in greater generalities.

I'm sure people will provide some other ways of thinking about this, but this is what jumped to my mind.

Comment: So it is just a way to simplify and have a better description of a function in a sense?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, so the parameter $t$ is just additional information to solve a function? Like knowing a particle's position with respect to time. You show me the time and will show you the position sort of way. I think it could be used as an additional description for the function as the example I just gave. It can also be used to have a better sense of what the function is doing and giving it the ability to solve a specific problem set?

Comment: That is one way of thinking about it. If (x,y,z) is a particles position, and you know the particle moves on the surface z=f(x,y), then introducing t as a parameter tells you the paths the particle follows as a function of time

Comment: Alright, thank you for your answer and clarification! Have a good day!